# Exclude directory from sourceSet not working in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I want to exclude a directory in Gradle .. I'm using the code below .. When I do a `minus` (i've also tried `exclude` the directory that I'm trying to remove is still present in `srcDirs` (when I output it at the end).

Suggestions ?

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
  test {
    java {
      srcDirs 'src/test/unit/java'
      minus 'src/test/java'            
    }
  }
}

task outputDirs << { sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}}
```

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this instead:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs  = ['src/test/unit/java']
        }
    }
}

task outputDirs << { sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs.each{f -> println(f)}}
```

This reassigns the list of source directories (here only one) to the srcDirs property. using

```
srcDirs  = 'src/test/unit/java'
```

as in your sample, just adds another source folder to the existing ones.

regards,
René

Comment: Thanks, that works .. second question: why didn't minus or exclude work?

Comment: Well, I try to explain it: all calls within the java closure

Comment: Well, some notes that may clarify the reason here: 
- srcDirs  'src/test/unit/java' in the gradle dsl is programatically a call of SourceDirectorySet#srcDirs(Object... srcPaths)
- SourceDirectory is of type FileCollection
- Calling minus on FileCollection does not modify the given fileCollection, but instead create and return a new FileCollection. That's why "minus" has no effect here.
- Simply spoken, excludes work in the same way as the "minus" call does here.
- There are some todos on the SourceDirectorySet interface to clean some stuff up here. Not sure if this cleanup will be part of 1.0